# Changing input values for every 2 clock cycles

Tags: verilog

How to write verilog code such that output values should change for every 2 clock cycles? I have written code for counter,it is changing/counting for every posedge of clock.I want, it should count after 2 posedge clock .How do i write code?

```
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
 if (rst)
  d<= 0;
   else
 d<=d+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TT flipflop for that case

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst)
        tt <= 1'b0;
    else
        tt <= ~tt;

    if (rst)
         d <= 0;
    else if (tt)
         d <= d+1;
end
```